# How to deactivate select-option with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

In the following HTML code I would like to realize the following with JavaScript. When the user selects `Audi`, he has only the option to select `application 2` (`application 1` has to disappear in this case).

```
<select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="app1">application 1</option>
    <option value="app2">application 2</option>
</select>
```

I wrote the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L2NFA/).

Comment: Do you want to remove the option or make it not selectable?

Comment: Is jQuery an option? You could take a look here for instance: http://calisza.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/6-jquery-snippets-you-can-use-to-manipulate-select-inputs/ A combination of sections 4 and 5 looks like what you're asking for?

Comment: removing or making it not selectable is ok, but the user must be able to select application 1 again, if he choiced Volvo

Comment: Though a bit late, [here](http://jsbin.com/ijonox/1/) is an [angular](http://angularjs.org/)-solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

html:

```
 <select>
  <option id="app1" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option id="app2" value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
 <select>
  <option value="app1">application 1</option>
  <option value="app2">application 2</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
var selections = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
selections[0].onchange = carSelection;

function carSelection(e) {
    var first = selections[0];
    var id = first.options[first.selectedIndex].id;

    var second = selections[1];
    var  j = 0;
    while (second.options[j])  {
        second.options[j].disabled = (second.options[j].value != id );
        if (second.options[j].value == id)
            second.selectedIndex = j;
        j++;
    }    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U4y2J/3/

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
 <select id="1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
 <select id="2">
  <option id="2a" value="app1">application 1</option>
  <option id="2b" value="app2">application 2</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("1").onchange = change;
function change(){
    var s_a = document.getElementById("1");
    var car = s_a.options[s_a.selectedIndex].value;
    var s_b = document.getElementById("2");
    if(car === "audi"){
        s_b.options["2b"].disabled = true ;
        s_b.options["2a"].selected = true;
    }
    else {
        s_b.options["2b"].disabled = false ;
    }
}
</script>
```

And **[link to fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/U4y2J/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

Automatically deselect `application 1` when `Audi` is selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/KQMLQ/1/

HTML

```
 <select id="1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
 <select id="2">
  <option value="app1">application 1</option>
  <option value="app2">application 2</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
$("#1").click(function() {
if($("#1").val() === 'volvo') {
    $("#2").find('option[value="app1"]').removeAttr('disabled');
}
if($("#1").val() === 'audi') {
    $("#2").find('option[value="app1"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled').removeAttr('selected');
    $("#2").find('option[value="app2"]').removeAttr('disabled');
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jQuery version [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/37ARZ/)
where I remove the option when the select is audi - it is removed based on values so you can have as many options you want surrounding the option to remove

```
var opts=[];
$(function() {
    $("#sel2 option").each(function(){ // save all options
        var opt = {};
        opt.value=this.value;
        opt.text=this.text;
        opts.push(opt);
    });

    $("#sel1").on("change",function() { // restore relevant options
        var sel = $("#sel2");
        sel.empty();
        var val = $(this).val();
        $.each(opts,function(i,opt) {
          if (val == "audi" && opt.value=="app2") return;
          sel.append('<option value="'+opt.value+'">'+opt.text+'</option>');
        });
    });
});
```